# Authorize Application Like Workbench

Tags: oauth, app, authorization, auth

I want to create an application that integrates to Salesforce - just like Workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php).

Every single guide I find wants be to create a connected app. Isn't it possible to authorize an app without first creating a connected app? I can see that gearset does the same thing. It can be authorized without creating a connected app.

Answer (score 2):

What you got to understand is that the Connected App record itself is an identifier for the application that is going to be using the Salesforce credentials. So you saying that "Gearset does the same thing, but can be authorized without creating a connected app" is technically wrong.

Gearset **does have** a Connected App that they have created in their own org. When you see the screen asking if you want to authorize the Gearset application, you are using Gearset's Connected App to handle the authorization process.

The first step to create an OAuth 2.0 application that connects to Salesforce is to have an org where this Connected App can be created. **It can be a Developer Edition org too**, if you don't feel like paying Salesforce for the service, by the way. An org can have multiple Connected Apps, so you can have the testing and production apps on the same org.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no. Everything that integrates with Salesforce needs a connected app.

[Gearset themselves do use OAuth](https://docs.gearset.com/en/articles/2288816-how-does-gearset-s-oauth-connection-to-orgs-work) (and thus, a connected app) to get a connection to your org(s). You don't need to explicitly create the connected app when you use Gearset because it is automatically "installed" for you in your org when you set up the connection between Gearset (or other things, like the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php), or Salesforce's own [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/data-loader), etc...) and Salesforce.

For Data loader and the Workbench, you need to authorize every time you use it. Some OAuth flows (mainly the Web-Server flow and User-Agent flow) can take this a step further by getting a "refresh token" so that you only need to explicitly authorize once.

The access tokens you get from using an OAuth flow do expire (their lifetime is determined by the session timeout policy in the connected app; profile; or org-wide setting, in that order), but using a refresh token, you can get a new access token once the current one expires.

Comment: So when I look for any documentation on web server flows it all needs client_id/client_secret which points towards a connected app somewhere. After the initial login with Workbench it seems the app is getting installed.

How does that happen? How do avoid having to do that step? Is that by installing the app elsewhere and then use that?

Comment: @SimonB.Nielsen Again, you cannot avoid using a connected app. You _MUST_ create one. The details of how a connected app gets installed isn't really documented, as far as I know. It's just a thing that Salesforce does for us. A connected app needs to be created in an org somewhere (and that's where the connected app "lives", so to speak. There is some configuration that can only be done in the org where the connected app lives). You can use that single, connected app in other orgs (no practical limit on the total number). When we do so, that's when Salesforce "installs" it in the other org.